# Excel function to replace value between two characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

We have about 100 lines of SQL config in the form:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4) VALUES ('xxxx', 'yyyy', 607,  SYSDATE);
```

We'd like to copy these 100 lines into an Excel sheet and replace the column3 numeric value (607 in this example) with a new number representing the row in the spreadsheet (ie: replacing the column3 values with numbers 1 through 100).

Note the values for column1 and column2 are variable length strings.  The value for column3 is always numeric of varying length.  Column4 always has a fixed value.

How can you write an Excel formula to do this replace?

Comment: That sounds like a dodgy xy problem. Why don't you use a function in the SQL query that auto increments?

Comment: What's the RDBMS? SQL Server? Why can't you use a `row_number()` function in that `SELECT` statement instead of hard-coding a literal that you don't need? If `row_number()` isn't applicable to your "real code", then you have under-spefied the problem and this isn't a [mcve]. FWIW having Excel to the job of a RDBMS is always a bad idea.

Comment: It's Oracle.  Yes we could use a sequence to do this if necessary.  Looking to spare the readers of the post the reasons why we are not looking to use a sequence to do this.

Comment: It's not clear how an `INSERT INTO` query relates to an Excel worksheet, either. I think your question needs further clarification. FWIW as it stands my answer would be "get the results into a `ListObject`/table with headings in row 1, don't select the column you don't need, and add a column to the table with [`=ROW()-1`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) for a formula: if that answers your question, then the SQL has nothing to do with the actual question, which is really "how do I get the row number from a cell in Excel".

Comment: Ultimately the question is how can you replace the data between the two strings.  This could be any string; the fact that it is SQL is unrelated to the question.

Comment: Again, your question is unclear. What is the context for that SQL query? Is it a string literal in some VBA code? What is the relationship between the SQL and the worksheet? Please [edit] your question to clarify and make a useful [mcve]. As it stands I don't think your question is answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a reason why you cannot do it in SQL, you mayjust use worksheet formula. Assuming that literal in in A2 cell, type:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2, SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,LEFT(A2, FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,FIND(")",A2))+1)+1), ""), ",  SYSDATE);", ""), ROW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Sub that does the following:

1. Start with a counter = 1;
2. Split the string by `,`;
3. Takes the prelast value of the array and put a counter value on it;
4. Increment the counter;
5. That's all.